# Caching links from a rss feed

Tags: php, mysql, caching, rss

I currently run a website that pulls in a rss feed and you can go to the links the problem i am having is when i click on a rss link it takes me to a webpage but that webpage will load really slow.

I am looking to cache that webpage so it loads really quickly, what is the best way to do this i can create a cache folder in my project and then cache each file to that folder and then serve from their example below.

```
<?php

foreach ($source_xml->channel->item as $rss) {

            $title          = trim($rss->title);
            $link           = $rss->link;

            $html = $title . '.html';

            $homepage = file_get_contents($link);
            file_put_contents('cache/' . $html, $homepage);

        }

?>
```

This takes quite long with alot of feeds and i am not sure if this is the most productive way i have also tried creating a database and have a extra field called cache that is a text field, i then store the output from file_get_contents in there example below.

```
<?php

foreach ($source_xml->channel->item as $rss) {

            $title          = trim($rss->title);
            $link           = $rss->link;

            $cache = file_get_contents($link);

            $data = array(
                'title' => $title,
                'link' => $link,
                'cache' => $cache
            );

            echo $this->cron_model->addResults($data);

        }

?>
```

This works but i get this issue when looking at the mysql

```
Because of its length,
this column might not be editable
```

I am not familiar with caching and have never really needed to deal with it since now can someone give me some best practise advice i know i can hack something together but would prefer to know the right way before going forward.

Thanks

Comment: "This works but i get this issue when looking at the mysql" --- why do you think it *is* an issue?

Comment: just because i am not sure whether the right column type is text maybe  i should be using a type that handles more text?

Comment: your question in the last comment is not clear.

Comment: I my mysql i have a column called cache which i am storing the html i have that column type set to text which i am not sure is the right type to using for lots of html

Comment: it is right type. If you data doesn't fit you could use longtext

Answer (score 0):

For better performance regarding caching with PHP + MySQL you can use memcached.

- [Memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php)

For further caching performance, you can utilize Opcode Caching and Meta Caching.

Opcode Caching

- [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php)

Meta Caching

- [HTTP EQUIV](http://www.metatags.org/meta_http_equiv_cache_control)

Comment: hi Mahbubur i have been reading thru using memcached so after installed it will cache everything within the database so memcached would be useful if i go for the storing all the webpages html content within my mysql database? thanks

Comment: Not necessarily for all webpages if you don't want. Just for RSS feeds you can use memcached.